# AdMob ID created 24hours ago still not available on the app

Tags: android, admob

I created an AdMOb ad unit 24 hours ago. The test ID works fine in the app but the real one is still taking a lot of time.

Here's what I have done on the mainactivity:

```
AdView ads;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    result= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.outputText);

    ads = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

    ads.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

Here's what I did in the XML :

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="31dp"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="id goes here" />
```

And in the manifest file I have added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Logcat:

> I/Ads: Starting ad request. I/Ads: Use
>   AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("111938875CFC9AB024C69BABE7ED487C") to
>   get test ads on this device

Do I necessarily  need to have a Google Play Developer account for AdMob to work ?

Comment: Do not use AdMob id in production and do not use it on your own device. Your id will be active first when your app is on google play.

Answer (score 1):

If your test Ad working fine with your App and you're not getting live Ads.

Follow these steps :

1. Wait for some times.
2. If you're able to load test ads but not live ads, it sounds like an issue with your AdMob account.
3. After waiting some times/hours if still having problem then you need to cross check Ad unit Id and AppId from AdMob account.
4. Make sure that you properly set up a payment system and/or verified your PIN? If they are not done, then live ads would not be served from your account.
5. Still problem now you need to post your problem in this [group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/android/fBe3YL3ffpo) for assistance.

No, you don't need to have a Google Play Developer account for AdMob to work.