# Rewarded video Google Live Ads iOS

Tags: ios, admob, rewardedvideoad

I have implemented ADMOB Rewarded video in my iOS app. I'm getting test Ads in my app when I use this line while requesting ads

```
request.testDevices = [ "bf7b2fcdb42c3a1095b2e0e4a0ea35ce" ]
```

If I'm not using this code, I'm not getting any Ads in the app and getting the error:

> Request Error: No ad to show.

How can I get live ads? If I can't get live ads until my app is live then how can my client see the Ads because the test Device ID is available through code. If my client doesn't see the Ads, he will not be convinced that I have implemented ads in the app. The Client communicates through emails and skype.

Any suggestion or even links are appreciated.

> **EDIT:** I have already implemented banner ads and interstitial ads and they are working fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AdMob ID created 24hours ago still not available on the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44744677/admob-id-created-24hours-ago-still-not-available-on-the-app)

Comment: @AbhishekAryan please check this code is for iOS and I'm specifically talking about the rewarded video, not about banner or interstial. I already have implemented banner. so that was not really helpful.

Comment: up vote, with the new SDK (7.23.0) the Rewarded video doesn't work. Before the new SDK  my reward video was visible

Comment: @SimonePistecchia Do you know how it can be resolved..

Comment: @ArunK I've open a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46105709/ios-admob-reward-based-video-ad-failed-to-load) seems that with test ID works