# iOS ADMOB Reward based video ad failed to load

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, sprite-kit, admob

until today I was able to show the reward video, but now the video doesn't appear, a log of admod alert me to install the new

> ADMOB SDK 7.23.0

Now with the new ADMOB SDK the reward video fails to load.

with the **test id**, seems to work:

```
GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().load(GADRequest(),withAdUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1712485313")
```

if I change with my reference ID, the video fails to load.
I've also added in AppDelegate:

```
//ADMOB
import GoogleMobileAds

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        //ADMOB
        GADMobileAds.configure(withApplicationID: AppConfiguration.AdMob.ID_APP)
        return true
}
```

Comment: did you reach your limit?  is your account temporarily banned?  Did you try asking google (literally ask google, not search)?

Comment: @Knight0fDragon hi man! Thanks to help me. I've another app with ad reward on the apple store and it's working in this moment. So I've tried to put the admob id of this app in the new one and don't works. I'll ask to google team as you suggest

Comment: It has been a while since I worked with admob, but don't you have to link apps in the app store to the admob account to get the production ads to work.  I thought a new bundle id would cause it to break.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

https://apps.admob.com/v2/home

Adding payments info can fix your issue.
Please refer the link.