# Admob Banner Ads don't display

Tags: java, android, admob, ads, banner-ads

I don't get an error, they just don't show.

In the manifest I have:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" android:maxSdkVersion="28"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
    android:maxSdkVersion="28" />
<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="28"/>
```

In the layout I have:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/publisherAdView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    app:adSize="BANNER"
    app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-??????????????/????????"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

(I used ? to hide my ads number)

In the Activity I have:

```
private AdView mPublisherAdView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_normal);
    MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-?????????????~???????");

    mPublisherAdView = findViewById(R.id.publisherAdView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mPublisherAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

This are my graddle files:

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "???????.?????"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1203
        versionName "1.2.03"
        testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
//GSON
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
//RecycleView
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
//ADS
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.1'
}
```

The thing is that the app uses internet because I can see I consumed X internet data, but the ads doesn't display. I tried everything, I followed the Google tutorials and copied what their webs say but I cant fix it. I looks like adds load because it takes a little to load the activity, and it didn't do so before, but the ad is invisible or something. I'm using an smartphone with API 26 so it's not the API level.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AdMob ID created 24hours ago still not available on the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44744677/admob-id-created-24hours-ago-still-not-available-on-the-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was Admob, for some reason my account wasn't validated, and that's why I though the problem was in the code, not in Admob.

Answer (score 0):

You have to build the `addRequest` properly using `AdListener`

```
mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .build();
mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded() {
      if (mAdView.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
            mAdView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       }
     }
  });
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

And the XML for Adview is

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ad_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    >
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        android:visibility="gone"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Its better to place your `banner id` inside your strings file.

Comment: It didn't work :/ I'm starting to think the problem is with Admob, because I can display a test ad, but not my own ads.

Comment: ooh okay. you are right. problem is with your adds.

Answer (score 0):

Your account may be not approved.
You can find out what the error is using:

```
@Override
public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
    super.onAdFailedToLoad(loadAdError);
    Log.d("ERROR",loadAdError.toString());
}
```

After you know your error you can fix it here:
https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9905175